# Interactive Grid: Column Filter disappears for columns having value in Cascading LOV Parent Column

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a child column and depends on a parent column value, filter/sort options are not available for the child column.

I'm facing similar issue posted on https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4313940/interactive-grid-column-filter-disappears-for-columns-having-value-in-cascading-lov-parent-column-s

I see the thread is closed as intended behavior. As a workaround, I tried creating two page items (LOV's) for parent & child and changed my IG query to include where condition based on the page items. So users can filter the data by page items. However that doesn't work either.

Does that mean there is no way to filter/sort the child items on IG?